# making new subarrays from two arrays with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am learning numpy, and I need to figure out how to create a new numpy array from two defined numpy arrays, where the new array is effectively a bunch of subarrays created from the elements of array 1 being "mapped" to the elements of array 2.

What I mean is, that for:

```
array1 = [6,8,9]
array2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

then the resultant array needs to equal:

```
[[6,1], [6,2], [6,3], [8,1], [8,2], [8,3], [9,1], [9,2], [9,3]]
```

I would like to know how to do this with numpy-specific functions (so no 'for' loops for iterating over the array elements individually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
import numpy as np

array1 = [6, 8, 9]
array2 = [1, 2, 3]


def mesh(values):
    return np.array(np.meshgrid(*values)).T.reshape(-1, len(values))


res = mesh([array1, array2])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[6 1]
 [6 2]
 [6 3]
 [8 1]
 [8 2]
 [8 3]
 [9 1]
 [9 2]
 [9 3]]
```